# When I pass Variable in php Via ajax It gives an error

Tags: php, jquery

When I Pass Variable to php It Gives an Error that is :

Notice: Undefined index: email in `C:\xampp\htdocs\TableTennis\admin\inc\chat.php` on line

```js
if(window.location.hash!=""){
  var search=window.location.hash;
        var result =search.split('=');
        var email=result[1];
   $.post("inc/chat.php",{email:email});
}
```

In PHP:

```js
<?php 
echo $_POST['email'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to access PHP page you post params to by just typing its URL in browser?

Comment: Try your email var name to something else, like emailAdd